# ¿Existe en español algún modismo que tenga el mismo significado de "to cut my teeth"?

Tags: traducción, solicitud-de-modismo

En inglés existe el modismo `to cut (one's) teeth` con el significado de aprender a hacer o dominar algo. A veces se implica  el matiz de "a muy corta edad" o cuando eres joven, incluyendo el matiz de "ya dominé esto hace mucho mucho tiempo". Otras veces el matiz es como de una experiencia "temprana" (cuando estás empezando con algo), como en el primer trabajo, por ejemplo.

> **To cut (one's) teeth**
>
> To gain experience with something, especially at a young age (when one's teeth would be coming in).
>
> [for a baby or young person] to have new teeth emerging through the gums.
>
> <sub>[Freedictionary](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/cutting+my+teeth)</sub>

Como el enlace indica, el modismo se basa en una analogía con los dientes que les salen a los niños que "cortan" la encía al salir. Algunos ejemplos más:

- Oh, I *cut my teeth* on those kinds of equations! Give me a challenging problem for a change!
- Jen may be young, but *she cut her teeth* at a prestigious journal, so her perspective and expertise will be invaluable to us.
- That actor *cut his teeth* on theater and other low-budget films. Those where his first jobs, and now he is ready for Hollywood.
- When I started to learn Spanish I *cut my teeth* on Mexican movies so I know a lot of slang.

¿Existe en español algún modismo que tenga el mismo significado de "Hace ya mucho tiempo que aprendí a hacer esto"? Yo en un primer momento pensé en la expresión "dejarse la piel (aprendiendo algo)", pero en este caso no tiene sentido porque no hay connotación de "aprendí esto hace mucho tiempo" o "lo aprendí cuando era muy joven".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Definitivamente, yo creo que la expresión que encaja en todos los ejemplos que has propuesto es:

> **[estar curtido en algo](http://dle.rae.es/?id=BlNrue5)**
>
> 1. loc. verb. coloq. Estar acostumbrado a ello o diestro en hacerlo.

Esta expresión tiene el sentido de haber aprendido algo hace tiempo, aunque no necesariamente de joven. Así, tus ejemplos quedarían así:

- ¡Estoy curtido en este tipo de ecuaciones!
- Jen se curtió en un periódico de prestigio.
- Ese actor se curtió en el teatro y en pelis de bajo presupuesto.
- Me curtí viendo pelis mexicanas.

Nótese que también uso directamente el verbo *curtir*, aunque con un sentido más parecido al del modismo que a la acepción 3 ("acostumbrar a alguien a la vida dura y a sufrir adversidades que puedan sobrellevarse con el paso del tiempo").

También se me ocurre el siguiente modismo, que encajaría solo en algunos de los casos:

- ¡Yo hacía esas ecuaciones cuando iba en pañales!

Aunque en este caso lo de "ir en pañales" no se suele tomar como que aprendiste a hacerlo de joven, sino simplemente que lo aprendiste hace tiempo.

Answer (score 2):

Para decir que tienes mucha experiencia en algo hay unas cuantas palabras y expresiones:

- Estar curtido en algo
- Ser perro viejo
- Avezado en estas lides

Pero ninguna de estas incluye el sentido de haber aprendido algo muy joven.

Comment: I do not think doing it at a young age is essential for the phrase cutting ones teeth to be used although obviously the first time you did something you were younger than you are now.

Answer (score 1):

### Desfogarse con/en algo - Dar los primeros pasos con algo

Creo que la expresión *cut your teeth on something* va orientada más a la "primera" experiencia, no tanto a que tanta experiencia ya se ha obtenido. Veamos estas definiciones:

En [macmillandictionary](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/cut-your-teeth-on-something):

**cut your teeth on something**

> to get your first experience in a particular job by doing something

Mi traducción:

> obtener tu primera experiencia en un trabajo particular haciendo algo

Como se ve, no se hace énfasis en cuánta experiencia se tiene, sino en que fue la primera.

En [collinsdictionary](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/to-cut-your-teeth-on-something):

> If you say that someone cut their teeth doing a particular thing, at a particular time, or in a particular place, you mean that that is how, when, or where they began their career and learned some of their skills.

Mi traducción:

> Si dices que alguien cortó sus dientes haciendo algo en particular, en un momento particular o en un lugar particular, quieres decir que eso es el como, cuando o donde se comenzó la carrera o se aprendieron las habilidades.

En [thefreedictionary](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/cut+your+teeth):

> If you cut your teeth doing something, you get your first experience of it and learn how to do it.
>
> Si cortas tus dientes haciendo algo, obtienes tu primera experiencia en eso y aprendes como hacerlo.
>   Ejemplo:
>
> He plans to cut his teeth on demanding theatre parts before making the break for TV and film.
>   El planea [...] en piezas de teatro exigentes antes de pasar a TV y cine.

Esta última frase me hace pensar también en "debutar", pero quizá no sea apropiada siempre.

Pensando en la expresión en español, los ejemplos [acá](http://dictionary.reverso.net/english-spanish/to%20cut%20one's%20teeth%20on%20sth) pueden ser útiles:

- foguearse con {or} en algo
- dar los primeros pasos con algo

La entrada para [foguear](http://dle.rae.es/srv/fetch?id=I9MD2xB) en la RAE:

> 2. tr. Acostumbrar a alguien a las penalidades y trabajos de un estado u ocupación. U. t. c. prnl.

Otra vez en Reverso Dictionary se ven ejemplos de ["foguearse"](http://dictionary.reverso.net/spanish-english/foguearse)  en contexto:
(Traducciones del sitio)

> Un hombre tiene que foguearse.
>
> A man's got to be seasoned.

y

> Tras foguearse en diversos grupos, hubo de esperar a cumplir la treintena para poder dedicarse a su vocación en cuerpo y alma.
>
> After gaining experience in a variety of bands, it wasn't until his thirties that he was able to devote his undivided attention to music.

Comment: *Foguearse* no lo había oído nunca, parece un sinónimo de "curtirse" que puede usarse perfectamente en tus ejemplos.

Answer (score -1):

Hola con respecto a: "lo aprendí cuando era muy joven", existe una frase que puede que sea equivalente. "cuando vos vas, yo ya fuí y volví tres veces". Denota, que uno es experto en el tema, y está sobre el interlocutor. Sí no es lo que buscas disculpa. Es lo que se me ocurre en este momento.

Comment: Esta respuesta aporta bien poco. Suena a localismo argentino, pero ni tu mismo estás seguro de haber respondido a la pregunta.